# $a_{n+1}=\frac2{a_n+a_{n−1}}$ . Prove that this sequence has a limit.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> The sequense $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_1>0, a_2>0$ and $$a_{n+1}=\frac2{a_n+a_{n−1}}$$ for $n≥2$.
>   Prove that this sequence has a limit.

I know I need to prove
 1) the sequence is monotone; 2) the sequence is bounded.

But sequense is not monotone.

Any hints?

Comment: Does _limited_ mean _bounded_?

Comment: @choco_addicted: Thank you. I edited

Comment: It need not be monotone actually. For example, taking $a_1=1$ and $a_2=2$ gives $1,2,\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}, \frac{17}{12},\dots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both $a_1$ and $a_2$ are positive, then $a_n$ is also positive for $n \geq 2$. Let us suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n (\geq 0)$ exists and is unique, and call it $L$. Then: $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{a_{n-1} +a_{n-2}} = \frac{2}{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n-1} +\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n-2}} = \frac{2}{L+L} = \frac{1}{L}.$$ So $L^2 =1$, or $L =\mp 1$. But we assumed $L$ to be positive.

Comment: Just add to you answer you assume the existence of a limit and if the limit exists is unique.

Comment: So if the limit exists, it is $1$.  But you still need to show that the limit exists.

Comment: But this does not prove that the sequence has a limit

Comment: This prove only that if limit exists then it is equal to 1.